# android annotations MyTask_(Context) has private access in MyTask_

Tags: android, constructor, private, public, android-annotations

I`m using @EBean MyTask class with androidannotations.I want to create new instance of the generated class like this

```
myTask = new MyTask_(this);
```

and it gives me error:

> Error:(65, 28) error: MyTask_(Context) has private access in MyTask_

Generated class has a private method:

```
private MyTask_(Context context) {
    context_ = context;
    init_();
}
```

The question is that what to do in order to android annotations can declare constructor *public*? or how can i access to private constructor?

Comment: What exactly is the `this` parameter you're passing into the constructor? As per the [docs](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes): *"An `@EBean` annotated class must have only one constructor. This constructor must either have no parameters, or, as of AndroidAnnotations 2.7, it may have one parameter of type `Context`."*.  Normally, you wouldn't call the constructor yourself, but rather have AA create an instance of an annotated class for you by annotating a field with `@EBean`.

Comment: I`m using AndroidAnnotations 2.7and _this_ = BaseActivity.this

Comment: I'm not too familiar with AA, but wouldn't you annotate a field with `@Bean` in your `BaseActivity` class in order to get a newly instantiated instance injected (assuming you haven't set the `MyTask` scope to be singleton)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should not instantiate the bean yourself, but inject it in a field via the `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
MyTask injected;
```

However, if you really have to, you can use the generated `getInstance_()` method:

```
MyTask task = MyTask_.getInstance_(context);
```

Comment: the problem is that inside MyTask class context is null

Comment: I do not understand the second comment. If you want to call `getInstance_()` manually, you are responsible to pass the appropriate `Context`. But in general, you should not call the method at all.